# Woodlouse that already infesting applied plywood floor

Tags: flooring, plywood, insect, rubber

I'm building a server room that is using plywood as its flooring, which unfortunately is infested by woodlouse, wood beetle, or some kind. I realize it just after the floor is finished being installed.

Since it is impractical to replace the flooring, I'm thinking about apply a new layer, rubber or vinyl flooring on the top of the plywood. The question is, will the insects, bugs, louse, or termites able to penetrate the rubber or vinyl layer? Or is there any more practical alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

well, I decided to tear down everything and replace it with concrete and granite floor. If I overlaid the infested floor, the pest would just eat the plywood until it was completely deteriorated